# why is web2py custom form, submitting even without {{=form.custom.submit}}?

Tags: forms, button, form-submit, web2py

I don't know what is happening, but my form is submitting even without the `{{=form.custom.submit}}` code.

---

```
        {{=form.custom.begin}}
            <div>{{=form.custom.widget.id}}</div>
            <div>{{=form.custom.widget.details}}</div>

            <div id="submit"><button></button></div>
        {{=form.custom.end}}
```

---

Take note that only `<div id="sc"><button></button></div>` is what I put.

What is happening, please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The default type for button elements is "submit", so your button tag acts as a submit button. If you don't want it to act as a submit button, than explicitly set its "type" attribute to something other than "submit", such as "button" or "reset".

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Comment: i did put the type as button a while ago, and it worked, i want the jquery to execute the functionality of the custom submit, i put in 'jQuery.ajax("{{=form.custom.submit}}")'; is this possible?

Comment: Does the above answer the question you actually asked? If so, feel free to accept it and then ask a separate question about Ajax form submission.